# MySQL Installer: Fails at creating user accounts

Tags: mysql, server, installation

Currently trying to install and start a MySQL Server on my machine. I'm using the original, actual Installer/Wizard. After filling out all fields, setting a root passwords and also telling to create one user with the password on localhost, the application fails at the step "Creating user accounts".

The log says:

> Attempting to Add New MySQL Users Authentication to host 'localhost'
>   for user 'root' using method 'mysql_native_password' failed with
>   message: Access denied for user 'root'@'localhost' (using password:
>   YES) Ended configuration step: Creating user accounts.

Interesting to note, I've done this on a testing device as well as on a fresh virtual machine. I've used different data and names actually, but with the same result >_< What could I be doing principally wrong?

Thanks in advance!

EDIT: Sort of solved... I re-downloaded the database alone and manually created users. Guess that's the better way when being about to learn SQL properly anyways.

Answer (score 5):

That error blocks your installation - although your MySQL server is running - it keeps you from installing the samples and examples. However, if you ignore installing these samples and examples, you can start **MySQL Workbench**. Moreover, the root account will be available with the password you have set during the install procedure (using Windows). Just launch the Workbench.

Comment: Yes, the workbench is how I created the users manually in the end. I still don't know what originally caused this error at all..

Comment: Windows, installing v8, port 3307, side by side install with v5.7 and I can't connect with the root password in workbench.

Answer (score 2):

For anyone still having trouble, a simple solution for me was making sure my user names and passwords did not contain special characters such as `\` `>` `~`, and so on. Characters such as `@` and `!` should work fine.

Comment: OMG this solved my problem. It's super retarded!

Answer (score 1):

I went back to the Accounts and Roles tab> "edit" on my user and my account said I needed a user name> reentered User name> save> next> rename MySQL> Execute== ran fine and finished install.

This was the easy way with all other updates for co-programs done already.